Calculating the arc length of a circular layer cut
As per the drawing attached, I am trying to get at the arc length of a
circular layer.

The problem constitutes itself as follows:

Let there be a circle with a known radius $r=219$

Let there be a known rectangle inscribed in the circle so as to cut a layer through the circle, where that rectangle's length $a=218$ and height $b=173$ are known.

Let this rectangle be at a known distance  $j=22$ from the circle's 90° radius and therefore at a known distance $k=24$ from the circle's edge, and let $b$ lie on the circle's 0° radius. The resulting circular layer $abc\beta$ is the subject of this problem.

Let the arc created by the section between this rectangle and the circle's edge, represented by a radius $f'$ and a radius $g$ be the unknown angle $\beta$. This angle is to be calculated as to its length. This angle can also be described between the rectangle's side $a$ and an imaginary hypotenuse $f$ of the triangle $bcf$. The triangle $bcf$'s ankathethe $c=99{,}7$ is also known.

Let the angle between between $\beta$ and the 0° radius be the unknown angle $\alpha$. This angle is to be calculated and the length of the arc to be derived therefrom.


The only reference to such a problem (perhaps lacking the necessary English terminology) I have found is this website https://rechneronline.de/pi/circular-layer.php which gives the equation $\gamma = 2 \cdot \arccos( 1 - (b+k) / r)$ and $\gamma + \beta =2 \cdot \arccos( 1 - k / r)$.
But if I plop the values above into its calculator, the result is definitely wrong. If I construct   the above in a drawing program or with a compass, pen and paper, the resulting $\beta$ is nowhere near (in radians or degrees) the claimed result from that website.
What do?

$c$ should be $\sqrt{f'^2-(j+b)^2} = \sqrt{219^2-195^2} \approx 99,7$.

The angle subtended by $\alpha$ at the centre is $\arccos\left(\frac{j+b}{f'}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{j+b}{r}\right)$; the angle subtended by $\gamma$ at the centre is $\arcsin\left(\frac{j}{g}\right) = \arcsin\left(\frac{j}{r}\right)$. Then the angle subtended by $\beta$ at the centre is $\frac\pi2 - \alpha - \gamma$.

I am not sure about your equation "$\beta = 2 * arccos( 1 - (b+k) / r)$". The $\arccos( 1 - (b+k) / r) = \arccos\left(\frac{r-b-k}{r}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{j}{r}\right)$, which is the angle subtended by arcs $\alpha+\beta$ together. And your equation even doubles this angle.

@peterwhy Peter, thanks so much. You're right, $c=99,7$. The equations you explain as incorrect are exactly what I also deduced to be incorrect, but were the ones given on that website :/. With your equations it works, thanks so much! How can I accept a mere comment as "correct answer"? If you want to post it as a formal response, I can credit you!

I am not sure about your equation "$\gamma = 2 \cdot \arccos( 1 - (b+k) / r)$". The $\arccos( 1 - (b+k) / r) = \arccos\left(\frac{r-b-k}{r}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{j}{r}\right)$, which is the angle subtended by arcs $\alpha+\beta$ together at the centre. And your equation even doubles this angle.
The angle subtended by $\alpha$ at the centre is $\arccos\left(\frac{j+b}{f'}\right) = \arccos\left(\frac{j+b}{r}\right)$; the angle subtended by $\gamma$ at the centre is $\arcsin\left(\frac{j}{g}\right) = \arcsin\left(\frac{j}{r}\right)$. Then the angle subtended by $\beta$ at the centre is either
$$\begin{align*}
\frac\pi2 - \arccos\left(\frac{j+b}{r}\right) - \arcsin\left(\frac{j}{r}\right)
&= \arcsin\left(\frac{j+b}{r}\right) - \arcsin\left(\frac{j}{r}\right)\\
&= \arccos\left(\frac{j}{r}\right) - \arccos\left(\frac{j+b}{r}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Thanks Peter! I've accepted this response as correct. By $l =  \beta \cdot r \cdot (\pi / 180)$ I got the arc length. Trebles all round!
